# populate gridview from xml

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, devexpress

I have `GridView` `mGridView` with 3 columns - `Process`, `Description` and `Type`.
I have `xml` with the content like this:

```
<root>
   <Rows>
     <Row Name="fdf" Description="dfaf" Type="A" >
     </Row>
     <Row Name="Sff" />
     <Row Name="XYZ" Type="PH">
     </Row>
   </Rows> 
</root>
```

where there are 3 Attributes (Name, Description and Type) and they are not obligatory. How to make the `DataSource` of `mGridView` to be this xml and every `mGridViev` `Row` to be filled with the 3 values of the tree atributes in the Row from the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your task properly, the following code with your xml file works fine:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(@"XMLFile1.xml");
        gridControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
        gridView1.PopulateColumns();
    }
```

Please also try to call the gridView's PopulateColumns method.  Does this help?

Comment: This code adds me all the rows but the problem is that cells are all empty without the values.